# Leaflet/JS: Adding polylines after pan/zoom

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using a Leaflet map as an image viewer, and I'm trying to add a 'toggle crosshairs' function that will place a crosshair at the center of the image.  I've got it working to a point where the crosshair appears correctly, and is 'coupled' to the image when doing pans/zooms, which is what I would expect to see.

The issue I'm having is that if I do the pan/zoom FIRST, and then toggle the crosshairs, the crosshairs appear in the center of the 'window', not in the center of the image.

The code I'm using for this is here:

```
toggleCrosshair(toggleVal) {      
    let map = this.map;              

    if (toggleVal == true) {
        var north = map.getBounds().getNorth(); // these are in lat, lng
        var south = map.getBounds().getSouth();
        var east = map.getBounds().getEast();
        var west = map.getBounds().getWest();

        var center = map.getCenter();

        var latlngHorizontalLeft = new L.latLng(center.lat, west);
        var latlngHorizontalRight = new L.latLng(center.lat, east); 

        var horizLineList = [latlngHorizontalLeft, latlngHorizontalRight];
        let horizLine = new L.Polyline(horizLineList, {
            color: 'red',
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 0.5,
            smoothFactor: 1
        });

        var latlngVerticalTop = new L.latLng(north, center.lng);
        var latlngVerticalBottom = new L.latLng(south, center.lng);

        var vertLineList = [latlngVerticalTop, latlngVerticalBottom];
        let vertLine = new L.Polyline(vertLineList, {
            color: '#A5CE3A',
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 0.5,
            smoothFactor: 1
        });

        horizLine.addTo(map);
        vertLine.addTo(map);

    } else {
        var i;
        for (i in map._layers) {
            if (map._layers[i].options.color == '#A5CE3A') {
                try {
                    map.removeLayer(map._layers[i]);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log("problem with " + e + map._layers[i]);
                }
            } else if (map._layers[i].options.color == 'red') {
                try {
                    map.removeLayer(map._layers[i]);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log("problem with " + e + map._layers[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any hints on how to get the behavior I'm hoping for?  Thanks!

Comment: How do you handle your image? Is it an ImageOverlay?

Comment: Yes, i'm using an ImageOverlay.

Answer (score 0):

map.getBounds() only gives you the geographical bounds visible in the current map view.

So in short, whatever you see on the screen.

Set it to the actual center lat lng coordinates.

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-getbounds

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses.  I ended up saving the original location/zoom value, moving the image to a known location/zoom value (using the SetView method), then adding the cross hairs, and then moving the image back to the original location/zoom values.  I did have to set the animation to false in the SetView calls...the timing of the animation threw things off.

Probably not the most elegant solution, but its something I remember having to do something similar when using Canvas elements.